# Animation to push/pull the title view out of/ into the screen

Tags: android, performance, animation

We need to have an animation to push the title bar view out of the screen and pull it into the screen. The title bar locates on top of the screen.

To do this specific animation will cost a lot for the screen that the animation is not smooth. I implement is in this way:

```
        ValueAnimator animDown = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f, 0f);
        animDown.setDuration(300);
        params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) titleView.getLayoutParams();
        animDown.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
               float currentValue = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
               newHeight = -(int) (titleView.getHeight() * currentValue);
               if (newHeight != lastHeight) {
                   params.setMargins(0, newHeight, 0, 0);
                   titleView.requestLayout();
               }
               lastHeight = newHeight;
            }
        });
```

this works fine in some places but not here, for I found that the callback method `onAnimationUpdate` is called very few times (say 6-8 times) during the animation, which means one frame update cost over 40ms, which looks too laggy.

My question is: is there a way to increase the frequency of the callback method `onAnimationUpdate`, or is there any other way to do this animation more smoothly?
Previously we are using other animations such as fade out and it works well, but `push out animation` here cost too much while the grid view list below the title view also is quite heavy.